# Thread exception without stacktrace

Tags: java, multithreading, exception

I set up global exception handler:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler());
```

with quite simple implementation:

```
public class DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler {

    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
        logger.error("Uncaught Exception detected in thread {}", t, e);
    }
```

}

sometimes I see in logs this exception several times:

```
[AWT-EventQueue-0] DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler - Uncaught Exception detected in thread Thread[AWT-EventQueue-0,6,main]
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: null
```

but I cannot find where it comes from.

How do you think, why stacktrace is empty? It shouldn't be empty, all threads must be created at least from parent "main" thread or any other.

Comment: Do other exceptions log properly including their stack traces? Just to make sure there is not a problem with the log call.

Comment: Stack trace doesn't contain parent thread information. It just contains the stack of the current thread, no matter which thread started it.

Comment: which library are the Logger and LoggerFactory in?

Comment: @RealSkeptic, yes, when I tried to print out throwable's stacktrace, it showed me the handler's method call.

Comment: @ControlAltDel, slf4j

Comment: Handler's method must have been in the same thread, then. Anyway, are you saying that you can get the stack trace directly from `e` yourself, but the logger does not?

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I don't see stacktrace nor through logger neither in System.out.println

Comment: So, what did you mean when you said *when I tried to print out throwable's stacktrace, it showed me the handler's method call*?

Comment: I assume that you are using this method
http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html#error(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object).
Try another method which accept Throwable as second argument.

Answer (score 3):

The JIT compiler can make some optimizations and "lose" stack traces.

You can use following JVM flag to disable this optimization:

```
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

Reference:
http://jawspeak.com/2010/05/26/hotspot-caused-exceptions-to-lose-their-stack-traces-in-production-and-the-fix/

Comment: I hope this works for JDK8. I keep getting a rare `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in the email notification from production that I can't reproduce and it's always empty.